# How can I detect if an html page element exists by using RoR RJS Template code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rjs

I tried several ways but all are failing.

Comment: It would help if you told us which ways you tried and failed.

Answer (score 3):

As dbarker mentioned, you can use `page['theElementID']` to test whether a specific HTML element exists based on its ID.

If your target element doesn't have an ID attribute, you can also check for it with a CSS selector, including class names. For example:

```
if page.select('div.comment').any?
    # Logic here if there is at least one comment
else
    # Logic for no comments
end
```

Documentation on `page.select`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html#M001632

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I couldn't get the

```
    if page[:element]
        # code here
    end
```

to work.  Instead, I ended up using

```
    page << "if( $('element') ) {"
        # code here
    page << "}"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [ ] method of the JavascriptGenerator to find an element like this:

```
page['theElementId']
```

Here's a link to the details:

[Module
ActionView::Helpers::PrototypeHelper::JavaScriptGenerator::GeneratorMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html#M001630)

Comment: Uhmm... have you tried it??? What happens if the element is not there?   What you described is a way to select the element ... I am looking for a way to detect existence.   The documentation online is not very clear.

Answer (score -1):

You could use what dbarker said like this:

```
 if page['theElementId'].nil?
       # then have you logic here if the element does not exist
 else
       # if the element does exist
 end
```